# Save data after user login for later use?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I use Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET Core.

When user login successfully, I want store some information of user (Ex: UserID, Name, Age ...) for later use in another controller.

In ASP .NET Framework, I basically store them in each Session.

For the example in ASP .NET Framework:

```
                    Session["UserName"] = UserInfo.UserName;
                    Session["GroupUserID"] = UserInfo.GroupID;
```

How can I do that in ASP.NET Core ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access to Session object via HttpContext within Controller as seems below

```
  HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", UserInfo.UserName);
  HttpContext.Session.SetString("GroupUserID", UserInfo.GroupID);
```

Besides you can also use TempData to store data in a request lifetime.